# Crash while casting object in swift

Tags: swift, crash

While trying to cast object the crash connected with releasing object is generated.

The problem can be narrowed to following code:

```
enum A: Error {
    case a
}
enum B: Error {
    case b
}
func errorHanlding(result: Result<Void, NSError>) {
    if case .failure(let error) = result {
        if case .a = error as? A {
            print("Success")
        }
    }

    return
}

errorHanlding(result: .failure(B.b as NSError))
```

This is the snipped of code that allows to check the root source. 
The problem is connected with this line:

```
if case .a = error as? A
```

Without this casting everything works correctly.

Doesn't anyone have idea why it is crashing?

Xcode version: 11.3.1
Swift: 5.1.3

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in a playground, the function simply returns. What crash are you getting?

Comment: objc[2072]: __SwiftNativeNSError object 0x7ffc45c65820 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug - this is the output that I have in playground

Comment: It seems casting Error to NSError causes this crash. You can use `Result<Void, Error>)` instead of `NSError`. There is similar [issue](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/649) about it.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk yes using Error instead of NSError is the fix I'm just trying to understand why it is crashing